# How do I find the probability of a distribution from 4 white balls and 6 red balls if 2 are randomly picked?

Tags: statistics

I understand this is a simple Statistics problem, but I'm just not sure what steps I need to take to get the answer. Feel free to edit anything if something doesn't make sense or leave a comment asking a question about it. If there is a similar question, leave it in the comment section. Thanks.

Two balls are selected at random from an urn that contains four white balls and six red balls. Let the random variable X denote the number of white balls drawn times the number of red balls drawn. Find the probability distribution. (Order your answers from smallest to largest x-value. Round your answers to four decimal places.)

(The question doesn't specify, but I believe it is without replacement)

\begin{array}{|c|c}
\ X& 0 & 1 \\
 & & &\\ \hline
 P(X=X)&  & &\\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: You need to specify whether its with or without replacement

Answer (score 1):

Here we use the pmf of hypergeometric distribution as 
P(X=X) ={4C(2X).6C(2-2X)}/10C2

Contingency table is as follows 
          Drawn           Not drawn           Total

White    k                       4-k                   4

Red         2-k                     4+k                   6

Total        2                         8                    10

EDIT  X=k/2